# How to create/update a recordset in a form with complex table relationship in Microsoft Access

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have these tables:

- **tblOrders** ('OrderId', 'Date', 'Client')
- **tblOrderDetails** ('Id', 'OrderId', 'Product', 'Qty', 'Price')
- **tblPriceList** ('PriceId', 'From Date', 'To Date', 'Client', 'Product, 'Price')

I have made a form based  on **tblOrders** where the user can enter: 'Date' and 'Client'.
Then i made a subform based on **tblOrderDetails** where the user enter: 'Product' and 'Qty' for each order line.
Now i need to display each 'Price' next to 'Qty', that depends on the 'Product', 'Client' and 'Date' of the Order line, as the **tblPriceList** indicate.
Also when i change the client or date in the form i need these 'Price' values to be automatically updated in the form and also in the table **tblOrderDetails**.

I managed to create a query joining these 3 tables, but then i was unable to create a new recordset in the form because of it complex relationship.
I also tried by creating a textbox in the **tblOrderDetails** subform with a Dlookup that gets the correct 'Price' from the **tblPricelist** for each order line. But then i didn't find a way to store this values in the 'Price' field from **tblOrderDetails**.

Is there any way to resolve this? Maybe a change in the database design?

Comment: Skip Price field in`tblOrderDetails`and determ the Price in a query field by joining`tblOrderDetails`with`tblOrders`on`OrderID`then join`tblPricelist`on`tblOrders.OrderID`,`tblOrders.Client`and`tblOrderDetails.Product`to get matchting Price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably when creating a new order detail, the user first selects a Product (from a dropdown?), and the Qty might default to 1.

o in your AfterUpdate event (using VBA) for the Product dropdown, put

```vb
Price = DLookup("Price","tblPriceList","Product = " & Me.Product & _ 
                                      " AND Client = " & Parent.Client & _ 
                                      " AND Date() Between [From Date] and [To Date]")
```

I'm assuming that the Client ID appears on the parent form somewhere in a control named 'Client'. Also put the same function in the AfterUpdate of the Qty, then you should be ok.

No need to use a complex query for Order details, just base the subform on the table, and use the Master/Child relationship to control it.

Are you reluctant to use VBA?

- It's easy, just right click the Product dropdown control, select Properties, then Events tab
- then click on AfterUpdate and select the elipsis. Click  'Code Builder' and enter your Me.Price = blah blah blah.
- Do the same for the Qty control.

Comment: That works perfectly. But, what if i suddenly decide to change the date or client? How can i update all that Prices without having to type again all the producst and qtys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I finally managed to do that with an AfterUpdate event for the client and date textboxes, that runs an update query with a DLookup in it.